# How to add months of two columns in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My requirement is I want to find out the accounts which are closed and getting expired after defined period.
I have account closure date (CLOSE_DATE) which is defined as TIMESTAMP and 
I have Retention Period (RET_PERIOD) in months

now I want to ADD months of CLOSE_DATE and RET_PERIOD.
so how could I extract number of months  from CLOSED_DATE and add it with RET_PERIOD?

e.g if account got closed on '03-Feb-2018' , I want to add RET_PERIOD which is defined in months (different for different account) in months of CLOSED_DATE then need to compare that SUM with Current Date and display it if it's greater than current date.

if RET_PERIOD is 3 months for account 111 then Sum should show me '03-May-2018'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add some number of months (for example, 4 months) which is stored in the `RET_PERIOD` column to some date (for example, '03-feb-2018') which is stored in `CLOSED_DATE` column.

If that's so, then `ADD_MONTHS` is what you need:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (closed_date, ret_period) as
  2    (select date '2018-02-03', 4 from dual union all
  3     select date '2016-02-29', 1 from dual
  4    )
  5  select closed_date, ret_period,
  6    add_months(closed_date, ret_period) result
  7  from test;

CLOSED_DAT RET_PERIOD RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------
03.02.2018          4 03.06.2018
29.02.2016          1 31.03.2016

SQL>
```

Comment: And notice that Littlefoot cleverly illustrated that Oracle handles the last day of the month correctly when adding one month to Feb. 29th and got the last day of March.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: another case is that Its RET_PERIOD column now having value "Permanent" i.e. I don't need to take any action against such records but due to this value I am getting ORA-01722: invalid number error , while using ADD_MONTHS function, how to avoid it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_months function. 
Example if 12 months is retention period:

```
ADD_MONTHS( CLOSED_DATE , 12) > CURRENT_DATE
```